Pod fails with FailedMount on PVC from Azure Blob Storage in Microk8s
I'm currently learning Kubernetes and getting the hang of it by setting up a Microk8s cluster on test machines I have. I'd like to be cloud-agnostic with compute resources in the cluster, so they are simple test VMs or anything not particularly tied to any cloud provider. Yet, for simplicity, I'm opting to use cloud services for storage only, as hostpath was great for testing but I got that it shouldn't be used in production so I'm trying something more real.
As a start, I opted to use Azure Blob Storage to provision storage in my test cluster. I used the blob-csi-driver to connect to Azure Blob Storage and set a storage class for it. I successfully created a PVC getting the "Bound" status. However, when I try to use this PVC in a pod, it fails with the following errors in the pod's events: reason FailedMount with error message MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume [...] timeout waiting for mount and directory is already mounted.
I don't understand how the directory could be mounted already, as I'm using a fresh Microk8s cluster each time I test this and the PVC is created and bound successfully specifically for this pod I'm trying to create.
Is there something I'm missing in the setup I made?
Below is all steps I took to set up the cluster, CSI driver, storage class, PVC, and pod for reference and reproducibility:

Set up Microk8s cluster:

# - Disable swap & firewall
# - Install Microk8s
sudo snap install microk8s --classic
# - In between tests, reset Microk8s
sudo microk8s reset
# - Enable basic addons
sudo microk8s enable dns
sudo microk8s enable ingress
# - Configure user permissions to access Microk8s & Kubectl, etc.


Set up CSI driver for Azure Blob Storage:

# - Ensure the master node has the necessary 'control-plane' label
# In Microk8s, the master node probably does not have this specific label
kubectl get nodes --selector='node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane'
kubectl label node my-vm-hostname node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane=''
# - Install blob-csi-driver
# Create to deploy on the control plane with 1 replica (only one node in the cluster for testing this right now)
helm upgrade --install \
    blob-csi-driver \
    blob-csi-driver \
    --repo https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/blob-csi-driver/master/charts \
    --namespace blob-csi-driver \
    --create-namespace \
    --version v1.25.0 \
    --set node.enableBlobfuseProxy='true' \
    --set controller.replicas='1' \
    --set controller.runOnControlPlane='true'
# - See the created resources and wait for them to be ready
kubectl get -n blob-csi-driver all

Created resources, as expected:
NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/csi-blob-controller-5d589dbc77-qvqln   4/4     Running   0          42s
pod/csi-blob-node-6t6g7                    4/4     Running   0          42s

NAME                           DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR            AGE
daemonset.apps/csi-blob-node   1         1         1       1            1           kubernetes.io/os=linux   42s

NAME                                  READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/csi-blob-controller   1/1     1            1           42s

NAME                                             DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/csi-blob-controller-5d589dbc77   1         1         1       42s


Create a storage class for Azure Blob Storage:

# - Create a namespace for the storage class configuration
kubectl create namespace blob-storage-class
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=blob-storage-class
# - Create a secret for the Azure Blob Storage account
kubectl create secret generic azure-secret \
    --type=Opaque \
    --from-literal azurestorageaccountname='azurestorageaccountname' \
    --from-literal azurestorageaccountkey='azurestorageaccountkey'
# - Create the storage class (non-namespaced)
# See the storage class as default for using it in the PVC
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
---
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: blob-storage-class
  annotations:
    "storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class": "true"
provisioner: blob.csi.azure.com
allowVolumeExpansion: true
volumeBindingMode: Immediate # WaitForFirstConsumer
parameters:
  csi.storage.k8s.io/provisioner-secret-name: azure-secret
  csi.storage.k8s.io/provisioner-secret-namespace: blob-storage-class
  csi.storage.k8s.io/node-stage-secret-name: azure-secret
  csi.storage.k8s.io/node-stage-secret-namespace: blob-storage-class
EOF
# - See the created resources
kubectl get all,secret,sc

Created resources, as expected:
NAME                  TYPE     DATA   AGE
secret/azure-secret   Opaque   2      42s

NAME                                                       PROVISIONER          RECLAIMPOLICY   VOLUMEBINDINGMODE   ALLOWVOLUMEEXPANSION   AGE
storageclass.storage.k8s.io/blob-storage-class (default)   blob.csi.azure.com   Delete          Immediate           true                   42s


Create a test application with a PVC using the storage class.

First, create the PVC:
# - Create a namespace for the test application
kubectl create namespace test-app
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=test-app
# - Create a PVC using the storage class
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
---
# Persistent Volume Claim
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: test-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
EOF
# - See the created PVC
kubectl get all,pvc

All works fine until here. The PVC is created and bound successfully:
NAME                             STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS         VOLUMEATTRIBUTESCLASS   AGE
persistentvolumeclaim/test-pvc   Bound    pvc-3c6c062d-9194-40ad-980c-c5677234205e   1Gi        RWO            blob-storage-class   <unset>                 42s

Also, the storage container is successfully created and shown in the Azure Web Portal, named after the PVC.
Then, create the rest of the test application using the PVC:
# Still in the 'test-app' namespace
# - Create a deployment, service, and ingress
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
---
# Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-deployment
  labels:
    app: test-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: nginx
          name: nginx
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          volumeMounts:
            - name: test-volume
              mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
      volumes:
        - name: test-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: test-pvc
---
# Service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    app: test-deployment
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
---
# Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: test-app.localhost
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: test-deployment
                port:
                  number: 80
EOF
# - See the created resources
kubectl get all,ingress,pvc

The pod is stuck in the ContainerCreating status:
NAME                                   READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
pod/test-deployment-65c7b4c555-sxzd6   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          42s

NAME                      TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/test-deployment   ClusterIP   10.152.183.148   <none>        80/TCP    42s

NAME                              READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/test-deployment   0/1     1            0           42s

NAME                                         DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/test-deployment-65c7b4c555   1         1         0       42s

NAME                             STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS         VOLUMEATTRIBUTESCLASS   AGE
persistentvolumeclaim/test-pvc   Bound    pvc-3c6c062d-9194-40ad-980c-c5677234205e   1Gi        RWO            blob-storage-class   <unset>                 69s

NAME                                     CLASS    HOSTS                ADDRESS     PORTS     AGE
ingress.networking.k8s.io/test-ingress   public   test-app.localhost   127.0.0.1   80, 443   42s

The pod fails with the following events (reformatted for readability):
kubectl describe -n test-app pod test-deployment-65c7b4c555-sxzd6

Events:
  Type     Reason       Age                From               Message
  ----     ------       ----               ----               -------

  Normal   Scheduled    2m17s              default-scheduler
  Successfully assigned test-app/test-deployment-65c7b4c555-sxzd6 to my-vm-hostname

  Warning  FailedMount  76s                kubelet
  MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "pvc-3c6c062d-9194-40ad-980c-c5677234205e" : rpc error:
  code = Unknown desc = failed to wait for mount: timeout waiting for mount
  /var/snap/microk8s/common/var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/csi/blob.csi.azure.com/[hash]/globalmount

  Warning  FailedMount  11s (x7 over 75s)  kubelet
  MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "pvc-3c6c062d-9194-40ad-980c-c5677234205e" : rpc error:
  code = Internal desc = Mount failed with error: rpc error:
  code = Unknown desc = exit status 1 Error: directory is already mounted
  , output:
  Please refer to http://aka.ms/blobmounterror for possible causes and solutions for mount errors.

Of course, testing the ingress doesn't work as the pod is not running.
curl -H "Host: test-app.localhost" http://localhost

<html>
<head><title>503 Service Temporarily Unavailable</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>503 Service Temporarily Unavailable</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>

And, after a while, the pod is still stuck in the ContainerCreating status, with the same error in events:
kubectl describe -n test-app pod test-deployment-65c7b4c555-sxzd6


The pod fails with the following events (reformatted for readability):

```bash
kubectl describe -n test-app pod test-deployment-65c7b4c555-sxzd6

Events:
  Type     Reason       Age                From     Message
  ----     ------       ----               ----     -------

  Warning  FailedMount  2m (x16 over 20m)  kubelet
  MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "pvc-3c6c062d-9194-40ad-980c-c5677234205e" : rpc error:
  code = Internal desc = Mount failed with error: rpc error:
  code = Unknown desc = exit status 1 Error: directory is already mounted
  , output:
  Please refer to http://aka.ms/blobmounterror for possible causes and solutions for mount errors.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. I don't understand the error or what could be causing it. I've tried redoing the setup multiple times and on two different machines with different OSes, but the same issue arises.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated as I'd really like to understand and learn from this.
Any alternative (better?) approach I could have taken to set this up would also be welcome.
Thank you in advance!
